# How can I use MVVM with the UI components of the App/activity and AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-asynctask, retrofit

As I know that the ViewModel should be secluded from the UI/View and contains only the logic that observes the data that's coming from the server or database

In my App, I used REST API "retrofit" and blogger API and I tried to migrate/upgrade the current code to MVVM but there are a few problems, let's go to the code

**BloggerAPI Class**

```
    public class BloggerAPI {

    private static final String BASE_URL =
            "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/4294497614198718393/posts/";

    private static final String KEY = "the Key";
    private PostInterFace postInterFace;
    private static BloggerAPI INSTANCE;

    public BloggerAPI() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
         postInterFace = retrofit.create(PostInterFace.class);
    }

    public static String getBaseUrl() {
        return BASE_URL;
    }

    public static String getKEY() {
        return KEY;
    }

    public static BloggerAPI getINSTANCE() {
        if(INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = new BloggerAPI();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public interface PostInterFace {
        @GET
        Call<PostList> getPostList(@Url String url);
    }

    public Call<PostList>getPosts(String url){
        return postInterFace.getPostList(url);
    }
}
```

this **getData** method I used in the Mainctivity to retrieve blog posts

```
public void getData() {
    if (getItemsByLabelCalled) return;
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    String url = BloggerAPI.getBaseUrl() + "?key=" + BloggerAPI.getKEY();

    if (token != "") {
        url = url + "&pageToken=" + token;
    }
    if (token == null) {
        return;
    }

    final Call<PostList> postList = BloggerAPI.getINSTANCE().getPosts(url);
    postList.enqueue(new Callback<PostList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<PostList> call, @NonNull Response<PostList> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                PostList list = response.body();
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body());
                if (list != null) {
                    token = list.getNextPageToken();
                    items.addAll(list.getItems());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                        items.get(i).setReDefinedID(i);
                    }

                    if (sqLiteItemsDBHelper == null || sqLiteItemsDBHelper.getAllItems().isEmpty()) {
                        SaveInDatabase task = new SaveInDatabase();
                        Item[] listArr = items.toArray(new Item[0]);
                        task.execute(listArr);
                    }
                }

            } else {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                int sc = response.code();
                switch (sc) {
                    case 400:
                        Log.e("Error 400", "Bad Request");
                        break;
                    case 404:
                        Log.e("Error 404", "Not Found");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.e("Error", "Generic Error");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<PostList> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "getData error occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getCause());
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

}
```

I created the **PostsViewModel** to trying to think practically how to migrate the current code to use MVVM

```
   public class PostsViewModel extends ViewModel {

   public MutableLiveData<PostList> postListMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void getData() {
        String token = "";
//        if (getItemsByLabelCalled) return;
//        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        String url = BloggerAPI.getBaseUrl() + "?key=" + BloggerAPI.getKEY();

        if (token != "") {
            url = url + "&pageToken=" + token;
        }
        if (token == null) {
            return;
        }

        BloggerAPI.getINSTANCE().getPosts(url).enqueue(new Callback<PostList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PostList> call, Response<PostList> response) {
                postListMutableLiveData.setValue(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PostList> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

and it's used thus in MainActivity

```
 postsViewModel =  ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PostsViewModel.class);

        postsViewModel.postListMutableLiveData.observe(this, postList -> {
            items.addAll(postList.getItems());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        });
```

now there are two problems using this way of MVVM "ViewModel"

1. first in the current **getData** method in the MainActivity it's contains some components that should work only in the View layer like the items list, the recyclerView needs to set `View.GONE` in case of response unsuccessful, progressBar, emptyView TextView, the adapter that needs to notify if there are changes in the list, and finally I need the context to used the create the Toast messages.

To solve this issue I think to add the UI components and other things into the ViewModel Class and create a constructor like this

```
public class PostsViewModel extends ViewModel {

    Context context;
    List<Item> itemList;
    PostAdapter postAdapter;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView textView;

    public PostsViewModel(Context context, List<Item> itemList, PostAdapter postAdapter, ProgressBar progressBar, TextView textView) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.postAdapter = postAdapter;
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.textView = textView;
    }
```

but this is not logically with MVVM arch and for sure cause memory leaking also I will not be able to create the instance of ViewModel with regular way like this

```
 postsViewModel =  ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PostsViewModel.class);

        postsViewModel.postListMutableLiveData.observe(this, postList -> {
            items.addAll(postList.getItems());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        });
```

and must be used like this

```
postsViewModel = new PostsViewModel(this,items,adapter,progressBar,emptyView);
```

so the first question is How to bind these UI components with the ViewModel?

2. second in the current **getata** I used the SaveInDatabase class use the **AsyncTask** way to save all items in the **SQLite** database the second question is How to move this class to work with ViewModel? but it also needs to work in the View layer to avoid leaking

the **SaveInDatabase** Class

```
    static class SaveInDatabase extends AsyncTask<Item, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Item... items) {
            List<Item> itemsList = Arrays.asList(items);
//            runtimeExceptionDaoItems.create(itemsList);

            for (int i = 0 ; i< itemsList.size();i++) {
                sqLiteItemsDBHelper.addItem(itemsList.get(i));
                Log.e(TAG, "Size :" + sqLiteItemsDBHelper.getAllItems().size());
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Will this be of any help ? https://medium.com/@sreeharikv112/android-unit-testing-clean-code-architecture-with-mvvm-73eb2992cab7

Answer (score 1):

Actually the question is too broad to answer because there are many ways to implement for this case. First of all, never pass view objects to viewModel. ViewModel is used to notify changes to ui layer with LiveData or rxJava without retaining the view instance. You may try this way.

```
    class PostViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<PostList> postListLiveData = new MutableLiveData<PostList>();
    private final MutableLiveData<Boolean> loadingStateLiveData = new MutableLiveData<Boolean>();
    private String token = "";

    public void getData() {
        loadingStateLiveData.postValue(true);
      
    //        if (getItemsByLabelCalled) return;
    //        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        String url = BloggerAPI.getBaseUrl() + "?key=" + BloggerAPI.getKEY();

        if (token != "") {
            url = url + "&pageToken=" + token;
        }
        if (token == null) {
            return;
        }

        BloggerAPI.getINSTANCE().getPosts(url).enqueue(new Callback<PostList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PostList> call, Response<PostList> response) {
                loadingStateLiveData.postValue(false);
                postListLiveData.setValue(response.body());
                token = response.body().getNextPageToken(); //===> the token

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PostList> call, Throwable t) {
                loadingStateLiveData.postValue(false);
            }
        });

    }

    public LiveData<PostList> getPostListLiveData(){
        return postListLiveData;
    }

    public LiveData<Boolean> getLoadingStateLiveData(){
        return loadingStateLiveData;
    }
}
```

and you may observe the changes from your activity like this.

```
postsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PostsViewModel.class);
    postsViewModel.getPostListLiveData().observe(this,postList->{
        if(isYourPostListEmpty(postlist)) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            items.addAll(postList.getItems());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });


    postsViewModel.getLoadingStateLiveData().observe(this,isLoading->{
        if(isLoading) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

For my personal prefer, I like using Enum for error handling, but I can't post here as it will make the answer very long. For your second question, use [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data) from google. It will make you life a lot easier. It work very well with mvvm and it natively support liveData. You can try [CodeLab](https://github.com/android/sunflower) from google to practise using room.

**Bonus**: You don't need to edit the url like this:

```
String url = BloggerAPI.getBaseUrl() + "?key=" + BloggerAPI.getKEY();

    if (token != "") {
        url = url + "&pageToken=" + token;
    }
```

You can use [@Path](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html) or [@query](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html) based on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your participation, firstly What's is `(isYourPostListEmpty(postlist)` I think you forget to declare this method in your answer
secondary after applying these changes, Should I removed the current getData method from the MainActivity? because I used it in different places like for example on the check connectivity of internet
`if (Utils.hasNetworkAccess(this)) {
            getData();`

on "swipeRefreshLayout" and onNavigationItemSelected, or I can simply copy from `if(isYourPostListEmpty(postlist)` till end and put this code into getData method in the MainActivity?

Comment: The reason I edit URL like this is that I need to add to use encapsulation to protect the class members like "BASE_URL" and the KEY this is most dangerous info and I shouldn't declare it as a public members so I created a getter also I need to edit URL to add the token to apply pagination to get next 10 posts, and I think you forget to add it `onResponse`

Comment: LoL. I left isYourPostListEmpty(postlist) for your implementation and thought the method name itself is obvious. How could I know the list is empty without knowing the response object structure and your code structure? You can use your getData method as you like. And for api part, those are not the proper way to hide your secret keys and use pagination parameter. Anyway it is just your choice and I can't provide full implementations as the network call itself can be a full blog post. Try reading the links I provided first and refractor your codes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As your question is bit broad , I am not giving any source code for the same, Rather mentioning samples which clearly resolves issues mentioned with ***MVVM***.

***Clean Code Architecture*** can be followed which will clearly separate the responsibilities of each layer.

First of all application architecture needs to be restructured so that each layer has designated role in MVVM. You can follow the following pattern for the same.

1. Only View Model will have access to UI layer
2. View model will connect with Use Case layer
3. Use case layer will connect with Data Layer
4. No layer will have cyclic reference to other components.
5. So now for Database, Repository will decide, from which section the data needs to be fetched
6. This can be either from Network or from DataBase.

All these points (except Database part) are covered over [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@sreeharikv112/android-unit-testing-clean-code-architecture-with-mvvm-73eb2992cab7), were each step is covered with actual API's .
Along with that unit test is also covered.

***Libraries used are in this project are***

1. Coroutines
2. Retrofit
3. Koin (Dependency Injection) Can be replaced with dagger2 is required
4. MockWebServer (Testing)
5. Language: Kotlin

Full Source code can be found over [Github](https://github.com/sreeharikv112/CleanCodeMVVMTesting)

### Edit

Kotlin is the official supported language for Android Development now. I suggest you should lean and migrate your java android projects to Kotlin.

Still for converting Kotlin to Java, Go to `Menu` > `Tools` > `Kotlin` > `Decompile Kotlin to Java`  Option

Comment: Thanks for the organized answer, I looked at this project but unfortunately, I don't know kotlin language till now, I know there are several projects about this topic but is there's a version with Java code?

Comment: You may not aware of Kotlin, but the structure remains the same. There is option in Studio to convert Kotlin to Java. I can put a reference in edited answer ... :)

Comment: More over Google is aligned to develop libraries for supporting  Kotlin. So learning Kotlin will obviously help you :)